# jmap -heap {pid} : throws java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, tomcat, heap-memory

I increased my tomcat Xms and Xms args via setenv.sh :

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms1000m -Xmx28000m"
```

but when i verify i got an exception ( NOTE: it has nothing to do with the values, it happen on another machine which i didnt set the Xms/Xmx)

```
$ sudo jmap -heap 17744
Attaching to process ID 17744, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.242-b08

using thread-local object allocation.
Parallel GC with 8 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 0
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 100
   MaxHeapSize              = 29360128000 (28000.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 349175808 (333.0MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 9786359808 (9333.0MB)
   OldSize                  = 699400192 (667.0MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:201)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: unknown CollectedHeap type : class sun.jvm.hotspot.gc_interface.CollectedHeap
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapSummary.run(HeapSummary.java:144)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.startInternal(Tool.java:260)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:223)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapSummary.main(HeapSummary.java:49)
    ... 6 more

$ /usr/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~16.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You have declared the maximum heap size to be 28GB. Does your RAM support this much capacity

Comment: @Rahul i got 32GB on this machine

Comment: do you resolve this problem ? many solution about this is to install an debuginfo rpm with identical version of the jdk. but I have this problem after install an jdk-debuginfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to install **openjdk-8-dbg**. This package provides the necessary debugging symbols for the utilities.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer